# Gridview not populating by datatable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

> Below is the code where The four columns("Challan Number","Proposal Number","CTS Number" and "Amount") is obtained from Sql-Database, and the ("Land" and "Ward") values are obtained from respective methods. The values obtaines are correct but still the "ChallanGridview" is not getting populated.
>   The datarow "dr1" gets populated with the correct required values, but the "ChallanGridview" doesn't shows anything.

```
public void FillChallanGrid()
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStrg"].ConnectionString;
    query = CtrlChallenSearch1.GetChallanQuery();
    using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"entry");
        int x = ds.Tables["entry"].Rows.Count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Challan Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Proposal Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("CTS Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
        dt.Columns.Add("Land");
        dt.Columns.Add("Ward");

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables["entry"].Rows[i];
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["Challan Number"] = dr["ReceiptNo"].ToString();
            dr1["Proposal Number"] = dr["ProposalNo"].ToString();
            dr1["CTS Number"] = dr["CTSNo"].ToString();
            dr1["Amount"] = dr["Amount"].ToString();
            dr1["Land"] = GetLand(dr["ProposalNo"].ToString());
            dr1["Ward"]=GetWard(dr["ProposalNo"].ToString());
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }
        ChallanGridView.DataSource = dt;
        ChallanGridView.DataBind();
    }
}

private object GetLand(string ProposalNumber)
{
    string retvalue = string.Empty;
    if (ProposalNumber != "" || ProposalNumber != null || ProposalNumber != string.Empty)
    {
        string[] splittedvalue = ProposalNumber.Split('/');
        retvalue = splittedvalue[1];
    }
    return retvalue;
}

private object GetWard(string ProposalNumber)
{
    string retvalue = string.Empty;
    string[] splittedvalue = new string[3];
    splittedvalue = ProposalNumber.Split('/');
    retvalue = splittedvalue[0];
    return retvalue;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillChallanGrid();
}
```

Comment: can you show your **.aspx code** of your program

Answer (score 0):

Its solved, I just deleted the present gridview and added another fresh one, 
don't know how and why, but the error was gone.
btw thnks  Asif.Ali!